# How to highlight duplicates rows based on more than 30 columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to highlight duplicate rows by Excel VBA code but I'm receiving a "'Range' of Object _Global' failed" error and I'm hoping someone can help as to why.

```
Sub Duplicate_Row()

Dim x As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim Z As Integer

x = 2
Y = x + 1
Z = 2

Do While Range("A:AA" & Y) <> ""
Z = Z + 1

Do While Range("A:AA" & Y) <> ""

If Range("A:AA" & x) = Range("A:AA" & Y) And Range("A:AA" & Y).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Then

Range("A:AA" & x).Activate

Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select

Range("A" & x).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
'Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = Z

Range("A" & Y).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
'Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = Z

End If

Y = Y + 1

Loop

x = x + 1
Y = x + 1

Loop

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

How to highlight duplicates in rows with msgbox ? I also want a msgbox for duplicate rows and highlight only those rows in which all the details are duplicate.

Comment: Is your data (starting in A1) in table format i.e. has it one row of headers? Do you really want to compare 27 cells per row? Is your data sorted by the 27 columns? You are using `xlToRight` which would suggest that your data spans beyond column `AA` i.e. there are more columns to the right. Is that true? Are you trying to use a different color for each duplicate row? Screenshots of your data before and after would do wonders. Please share any additional information best by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74442514/edit).

Answer (score 0):

As my late father used to say "*When you can do something the difficult way, then why do it the easy way?*" and this is exactly what I see when reading your question. :-)

I have made a small Excel file, highlighting duplicates, using conditional formatting, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

(It's all about column "A", the others are just there for explanatory reasons: "B" contains the formula results, "C" contains the `=FormulaText(Bn)` formula.)

The formula this is based on, is: `=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)-1`.
Some explanation: this formula (you can see the results in the second column) counts the amount of times that `An` (which is what you get by dragging down `A1`) is present in the range `A1:An` (the first cell `A1` is fixed because of the dollar-signs in the formula), minus one (in order not to count the cell value itself. As a result, when the value gets found before (a duplicate), the value gets 1 or higher, and when the value does not get found before, you get a zero. Conditional formatting can be based on formulae: `TRUE` or non-values get highlighted.